# How to obtain descriptor identifier for a AD Group using Azure Devops REST API

Tags: azure-devops

Hello stackoverflow community. Is there a way for us to obtain the descriptor identifier of the AD User group? any rest api endpoint for that purpose? given that we know the exact name of the AD group

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Descriptor Identifier using devops REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239591/finding-descriptor-identifier-using-devops-rest-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. This was my solution:

First: [Graph->List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Can get Group descriptor, like this
[image]

Second: [Identities->Read Identities API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-identitydescriptors)

Like this: [https://vssps.dev.azure.com/v-heyanhe/_apis/identities?subjectDescriptors={The](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/v-heyanhe/_apis/identities?subjectDescriptors=%7BThe) descriptor From First Step}&api-version=6.0
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to [list the groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#graphgroup) and pull out the one you want. The [GraphGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#graphgroup) object has the **descriptor** property.

The [Samples Repo for the .net client libraries](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/Graph/GroupsSample.cs) has some code to show how the api works.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all groups in account.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [ClientSampleMethod]
        public PagedGraphGroups GetAllGroups()
        {
            VssConnection connection = Context.Connection;
            GraphHttpClient graphClient = connection.GetClient<GraphHttpClient>();
            PagedGraphGroups groups = graphClient.ListGroupsAsync().Result;

            foreach (var group in groups.GraphGroups)
            {
                LogGroup(group);
            }

            return groups;
        }
```

Comment: thank you for the response. However, It seems like the descriptor i get from the graph api is not the descriptoridentifier that I am looking for the AD Group.

Comment: What is the value you're expecting to get that tells you it's not right?

Comment: I am trying to make a post to the 

https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/{namespaceId}?api-version=5.1



{
                "token": "",
                "merge": true,
                "accessControlEntries": [
                    {
                        "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-**********-**********-**********-**********-**********-*-**********-**********-**********-**********",
                        "allow": 128,
                        "deny": 0
                    }
                ]
            }

Answer (score 0):

The descriptor lookup needs to happen at organization scope but with a [TEAM FOUNDATION] prefix. Using the Azure CLI with the `devops` extension:

```
$descriptor = az-ps devops security group list --org $org --scope organization --output json --query "graphGroups[?principalName == '[TEAM FOUNDATION]\$($groupName)'].descriptor | [0]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the group descriptor by using [the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli), like this:

```
az devops security group list --project "Your Azure DevOps Project Name Here"
```

That will list all of the security groups that have been assigned a role in the team project. If you don't see your group in the list, then just go add the group to one of the permission roles in the team project (e.g. Readers) and it should show up.

From there just find your group in the list and grab its `descriptor` field.